Why doesn't TypeScript remember the positions and types of array elements?
I'm trying to create an array of objects comprised of a questions, an associated action to perform(a function) and arguments to supply to the function. I don't understand why typescript cannot understand the type and arguments, I would also like to understand how to achieve such functionality.
My code runs and returns what I expect but typescript is not happy...
playground
type Digit = 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9;
const Color = {
  red: 0,
  black: 1,
} as const;
type Color = typeof Color[keyof typeof Color];
type Code = {
        value: Digit,
        color: Color
}
function countOfEven(codes: Code[]): number {
  return codes.filter((code) => code.value % 2 === 0).length;
}
 function countOfColor(codes: Code[], color: Color): number {
  return codes.filter((code) => code.color === color).length;
}
let code: Code [] = [
        {
        value: 1,
        color: Color.black
        },
        {
        value: 2,
        color: Color.red      
        }
]
const questions = [
  {
    body: "How many even numbers?",
    action: countOfEven,
  },
  {
    body: "How many red numbers?",
    action: countOfColor,
    args: Color.red
  }]
  
let question1 = questions.at(0)
let question2 = questions.at(1);

console.log(question1?.body,question1?.action(code)) // error!
//                                     ~~~~~~
// Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

console.log(question2?.body,question2?.action(code,question2.args)) // error!
//                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '0 | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Color'.
//  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Color'.



OK, the types don't work in your example but the code wouldn't have worked even if it was correct. You are calling question1?.action() yet that requires an argument. You also call question2?.action(question2.args) yet that requires two arguments and you are only passing something that satisfies the second argument.

• Please [edit] to include the error message in the question so this is a [mre] (saying "TypeScript is not happy" isn't sufficient, and we also can't require people navigate to the ts playground in order to see the problem). If you want I can do the edit for you.

(see prev comment)  • There are two issues here, one is that questions's type is an unordered array, so you need something like as const there if you want TS to keep track of the indices of the questions. The other is that at() isn't strongly typed enough as per ms/TS#47660 so you'd be better off using direct numeric indexing; if you do both as shown in this playground then it starts working. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

I edited the post to add the error message, and your solution is great! I didn't realise the ordering is not kept track of and the issue with at(), please feel free to edit the post further if anything else needs adding.

You have two problems: TypeScript doesn't know which action is at which position in the questions array; and TypeScript does not know how to strongly type the results of its at() method

The first problem. Let's look at the type of questions:
const questions = [
  {
    body: "How many even numbers?",
    action: countOfEven,
  },
  {
    body: "How many red numbers?",
    action: countOfColor,
    args: Color.red
  }]

/* const questions: (
    { body: string; action: (codes: Code[]) => number;  args?: undefined; } | 
    { body: string; action: (codes: Code[], color: Color) => number; args: 0; }
  )[] */

Notice how it's of the form ({⋯} | {⋯})[].
That's a plain array type (unordered and of arbitrary length) and each element is of a union type.  TypeScript has no idea that position 0 holds a (codes: Code[]) => number or that position 1 holds a (codes: Code[], color: Color) => number.
If you want TypeScript to keep track of the position and types of each element, you need to use a tuple type instead. The easiest way to get such a type inferred for you is to use a const assertion:
const questions = [{ ⋯✂⋯ }] as const;
         
/* const questions: readonly [{
    readonly body: "How many even numbers?";
    readonly action: (codes: Code[]) => number;
}, {
    readonly body: "How many red numbers?";
    readonly action: (codes: Code[], color: Color) => number;
    readonly args: 0;
}] */

That might be a little more specific than you want, but at least TypeScript knows which element is at which position.

The second problem. The return type of at() doesn't depend on its argument, so you get a union of all the element types, including undefined:
let question1 = questions.at(0);
/* let question1: {
    readonly body: "How many even numbers?";
    readonly action: (codes: Code[]) => number;
} | {
    readonly body: "How many red numbers?";
    readonly action: (codes: Code[], color: Color) => number;
    readonly args: 0;
} | undefined */

let question2 = questions.at(1);
/* let question2: {
    readonly body: "How many even numbers?";
    readonly action: (codes: Code[]) => number;
} | {
    readonly body: "How many red numbers?";
    readonly action: (codes: Code[], color: Color) => number;
    readonly args: 0;
} | undefined */

There was a suggestion to support a strongly typed return for at() at microsoft/TypeScript#47660, but it was declined as too complex.
The easiest workaround here is to forget about at() and just use numeric indexing with brackets (which is by far the most common way to do this):
let question1 = questions[0];
/* let question1: {
    readonly body: "How many even numbers?";
    readonly action: (codes: Code[]) => number;
} */

let question2 = questions[1];
/* let question2: {
    readonly body: "How many red numbers?";
    readonly action: (codes: Code[], color: Color) => number;
    readonly args: 0;
} */

And now TypeScript knows the exact type of each question, and you can access them accordingly:
console.log(question1.body, question1.action(code))
console.log(question2.body, question2.action(code, question2.args))

You don't even need optional chaining, since TypeScript knows that neither question1 nor question2 are undefined.
Playground link to code

I appreciate the explanation, great work!
